# signing PDF files in Python with signpdf module

Tags: python, function, pdf, arguments

SO I downloaded the "signpdf" module. I am having trouble putting the arguments in the correct order in order to get the function to work. Below is my code as well as what documentation i could find online:

```
import PyPDF2
import reportlab
import signpdf



signpdf("contract.pdf", "sig.png", --"coords 1x100x100x150x40")



"""
signpdf contract.pdf sig.png --coords 1x100x100x150x40

usage: Add signatures to PDF files [-h] [--date] [--output [OUTPUT]] [--coords [COORDS]] pdf signature

positional arguments:
  pdf                The pdf file to annotate
  signature          The signature file (png, jpg)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --date
  --output [OUTPUT]  Output file. Defaults to input filename plus '_signed'
  --coords [COORDS]  Coordinates to place signature. Format: PAGExXxYxWIDTHxHEIGHT. 1x200x300x125x40 means page 1, 200
                     units horizontally from the bottom left, 300 units vertically from the bottom left, 125 units
                     wide, 40 units tall. Pages count starts at 1 (1-based indexing). Units are pdf-standard units
                     (1/72 inch).



Coordinates format is: <pagenum>x<x-coord>x<y-coord>x<width>x<height>.

<pagenum> the page number, count starts at 1.
<x-coord> horizontal distance from bottom-left corner in PDF units (1/72 inch).
<y-coord> vertical distance from bottom-left corner in PDF units (1/72 inch).
<width> width of signature in PDF units (1/72 inch).
<height> height of signature in PDF units (1/72 inch)
Other options:

--date Append a date to the right of the signature.
--output Destination filename. Default is to append _signed to the incoming PDF name.
For more usage details, run signpdf --help.
"""
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what does not work? Do you get any error?

Comment: This is the error that i get:
    signpdf("contract.pdf", "sig.png", --"coords 1x100x100x150x40")
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Comment: Now I see it, why do you have `--` before `"coords 1x100x100x150x40"`? That error will go away if you remove that

Comment: I tried that and now i have this error:

signpdf("contract.pdf", "sig.png", "coords 1x100x100x150x40")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: from the docs you posted signpdf is meant to be used from the command line so you should do `signpdf contract.pdf sig.png --coords 1x100x100x150x40` from a terminal where this is installed